# Keyboard acts as though SHIFT is stuck

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, keyboard

I am running a Windows 10 laptop and some of the keys are not working, such as "K", and all numbers (I currently use a USB keyboard anyway, since it feels easier -- plus all the keys from it work. BUT the problem being typed still remains below, even on the USB keyboard)

One of these (being the most important of them all since I use a USB keyboard anyway) is the SHIFT key. Mainly the right shift key, turning all my numbers from "123" to "!@#", and all letters cap. Using the "Caps Lock" key while this troublesome thing is going on, I can revert to small letters, but not numbers. I'm well aware that this is caused by dirt or ants or something of the sort -- as this laptop wasn't being used often before and it was just sitting there. (It wasn't mine, but a friend's at the time. I had a desktop). But if I can just disable the laptop's keyboard, then a USB keyboard should work, right?

I tried to uninstall the standard PS/2 Keyboard, but then it asks me to restart for it to work, and when it turns on again... the keyboard is still there.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of uninstalling the keyboard, try using Device Manager to Disable the keyboard. Its worth a shot. if not, rip the shift button off the board.

https://www.itsupportguides.com/windows-10/windows-10-how-to-disable-devices-using-the-device-manager/

Comment: Hey there. I couldn't find anything to "disable" it. I read this once and looked around before. And the key itself has been ripped off, but not the actual "button". I'm waiting to see if there's anything I can do before I end up having to do that.

Comment: You read the link Included? It should have had disable option. If not, disable the PS/2 device instead.

Comment: Did you follow the link above? You should have the option to disable the keyboard, if not, disable the PS/2 bus device.

Comment: Yeah, I read the link and followed it, but....There's no "disable" option.

Comment: Go to Device Manager and select the keyboard driver for your laptop. Right-clic-> Properties Click on the rdiver panel and select the "Update..." button. Here you can choose an incompatible driver (you should unselect the option "Find compatible driver"). The one I have chosen (and the safer) is the "HID Keyboard Device" Restart and that's it !! Your are done

Comment: So I'm at the part where you have to unselect the option, "Find compatible driver". What do I do now? Go to "(Standard Keyboards)? Because I found only, "PS/XT PS/2 Keyboard (84-key), "Standard PS/2 101 102 Keyboard", and "Standard PS/2 Keyboard".

Comment: Unselect Find compatible driver

Comment: Then choose HID

Comment: Hello (sorry about the bad English going on here as the keyboard is acting up)

It seemed to work for a bit but not anymore

First off: restarting the device seems to just bring the original keyboard back
SO I tried NOT restarting the device and it DID work sometimes
But not anymore